# Is anything wrong with my configuration of nova keystone and glance cannot create vms

Tags: python, openstack

i just set up a development environment of openstack in one node of my Desktop ,and i confirm that it supports virtualization .My question here is that after installaion and start the basic component of openstack , keystone, nova, glance , uploaded the images. but i cannot create any active vm instance all of them are in building state.
Below is my nova.conf and glance

```
 [willier@cloud ~]$ cat /etc/nova/nova.conf
 [DEFAULT]
  verbose=True
  auth_strategy=keystone
  allow_resize_to_same_host=True
  api_paste_config=/etc/nova/api-paste.ini
  rootwrap_config=/etc/nova/rootwrap.conf
  compute_scheduler_driver=nova.scheduler.filter_scheduler.FilterScheduler
  dhcpbridge_flagfile=/etc/nova/nova.conf
  force_dhcp_release=True
  fixed_range=10.0.0.0/24
  default_floating_pool=nova
  s3_host=192.168.1.110
  s3_port=3333
  osapi_compute_extension=nova.api.openstack.compute.contrib.standard_extensions
  my_ip=192.168.1.110
  sql_connection=mysql://root:nomoresecret@localhost/nova?charset=utf8
  libvirt_type=kvm
  libvirt_cpu_mode=none
  instance_name_template=instance-%08x
  enabled_apis=ec2,osapi_compute,metadata
  volume_api_class=nova.volume.cinder.API
  logdir = /var/log/nova
  state_path=/opt/data/nova
  lock_path=/opt/data/nova
  instances_path=/opt/data/nova/instances
  logging_context_format_string=%(asctime)s %(color)s%(levelname)s %(name)s [%    (request_id)s %(user_name)s %(project_name)s%(color)s] %(instance)s%(color)s%(message)s
  logging_default_format_string=%(asctime)s %(color)s%(levelname)s %(name)s [-%(color)s] %(instance)s%(color)s%(message)s
  logging_debug_format_suffix=from (pid=%(process)d) %(funcName)s %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d
  logging_exception_prefix=%(color)s%(asctime)s TRACE %(name)s %(instance)s
  network_manager=nova.network.manager.FlatDHCPManager
  public_interface=br100
  vlan_interface=wlan0
  flat_network_bridge=br100
  flat_interface=wlan0
  novncproxy_base_url=http://127.0.0.1:6080/vnc_auto.html
  xvpvncproxy_base_url=http://127.0.0.1:6081/console
  vncserver_listen=127.0.0.1
  vncserver_proxyclient_address=127.0.0.1
  ec2_dmz_host=192.168.1.110
  rabbit_host=localhost
  rabbit_password=flopsymopsy
  glance_api_servers=127.0.0.1:9292
  compute_driver=libvirt.LibvirtDriver
  firewall_driver=nova.virt.libvirt.firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver
```

br100 a made by follows:

```
 [root@cloud nova]# cat /etc/networks 
 default 0.0.0.0
 loopback 127.0.0.0
 link-local 169.254.0.0

 auto br100
 iface br100 inet static
    address 10.0.0.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    bridge_ports wlan0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0

[root@cloud nova]# brctl addbr br100
[root@cloud nova]# ifconfig br100 up
```

I can be online using wlan0 so i makd a bridge to wlan0. And my nics are belows:

```
 br100: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::284f:d0ff:fe46:d481  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2a:4f:d0:46:d4:81  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3  bytes 238 (238.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e8:9a:8f:a4:60:c3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 16436
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 18955  bytes 2133278 (2.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18955  bytes 2133278 (2.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 5e:70:0a:39:e8:9f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::3a59:f9ff:fe9e:b801  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 38:59:f9:9e:b8:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 46063  bytes 24525906 (23.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 37038  bytes 7529152 (7.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I would be really appreciate if anyone can give me some advices

Comment: This question is likely to be closed since it isn't programming related. The first thing you should do is check your log files (/var/log/nova/nova-*.log) for error messages. If you're still stuck, try asking on the openstack or openstack-operators mailing lists, see http://wiki.openstack.org/MailingLists

Comment: What errors are you seeing?  Behaviour?